# How can I delay audio in an mp4 file?

Tags: audio, mp4

How can I delay the audio (relative to the video stream) in an MP4 movie file and save the result?

Comment: Please tell us what exactly do you mean by "delay the audio"? (OS version would help too)

Comment: Tried to make the question more clear. Why does OS version matter?

Comment: OS version matters because you'd be surprised at the number of questions that come from users using Windows and stuff like that. It happens.

Comment: Ah, ok. Thought you were talking about mp4 Audio Files. Thanks for the editing your question. Deleted my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use the free app [QTSync](http://www.qtsync.com/qtsync.php) which supports this feature.

Answer (score -1):

VLC supports audio delay and re-encoding.

Answer (score -1):

You can use some tools listed here it help you http://techhowdy.com/mp4-to-mp3-converter-online/

Comment: Answers on Ask Different need to be more than just a link. It's okay to include a link, but please summarize or excerpt it in the answer. The idea is to make the answer stand alone and describe how the tool you recommend can be used to solve the problem stated in the question. Also please have a look at http://apple.stackexchange.com/help/behavior, especially the part about self-promotion.